# How to run a folder which contains several php files with xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

When I try localhost/myfiles opens just file list but i need those files to run. How can i run all xxxx.php at the same time? For exmple: I have a folder my files and it contains: a.php, b.php,c.php, so how run a,b and c files together?

Comment: use localhost/myfiles.php  or create index file Php on a directory and then run locallhost/yourfolder/    And be sure of that your Xampp server has started apache

Comment: How do you mean _you want to run all the files at once_ That does not make a lot of sence

Comment: What do you mean "run a folder", "run a,b and c together"? You can only run one .php file, what are you trying to do? If you don't want to see the files in the folder you'd need an index file, like `localhost/myfiles/index.php`, which will be run "automagically" when you visit `localhost/myfiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a PHP file like **main.php** on a directory and then use
the statement include and  attach your files to it

for example:

```
<?php
include 'a.php';
include 'b.php';
include 'c.php';
.
.
.
?>
```

type on browser

```
locallhost/yourDirectory/main.php
```